# How do I color a string in python terminal?

Tags: python, string, input, terminal, colors

I am trying to color only a single variable in Python 3, however whenever I run the code, the sring gets colored in my terminal, but then everything else after that is colored too. I am trying to do it without any imports. Here's my code.

```
tentativas = 20
print(f'Tentativas restantes:', f'\033[0;36m {tentativas}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the coloring you have to use `"\033[0;0m"`, either set it up as a prefix in your next print
e.g.

```py
print("\033[0;0m This is your next print")
```

Or perform an empty print just to reset the color

```py
print("\033[0;0m", end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module colorama

Install:
pip install colorama

Open script
from colorama import Force as color

Answer (score 0):

When using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), e.g. `\033[0;36m`, best practice is to  always reset the colour/style with `\033[0;0m`. Otherwise, the colour/style will spill over into subsequent messages in the terminal. Your example should then be:

```py
tentativas = 20
print(f'Tentativas restantes:', f'\033[0;36m {tentativas}\033[0;0m')
```

If you don't mind, allow me to refactor your code so it's a little easier to read:

```py
class Color():
  CYAN = '\033[0;36m'
  OFF = '\033[0;0m'

tentativas = 20

print(f'Tentativas restantes: {Color.CYAN}{tentativas}{Color.OFF}')
```

[image]

Though you don't plan to use a Python package, you may want to consider making your code even easier to read. With [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) (yes, I'm the author in full disclosure), your example could look like this:

```py
from colorist import Color

tentativas = 20

print(f'Tentativas restantes: {Color.CYAN}{tentativas}{Color.OFF}')
```